# Loading a script that requires an access token via command

Tags: php, oauth

I use the following code to generate an access token with the Instagram API.

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
$client_id = '123456789';
$client_secret = '8cf03fedc8bb44f1beccb0ffb529b487';
$redirect_uri = 'http://testsite.com/redirect.php';
$scope = 'relationships';
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=".$client_id."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&scope=".$scope."&response_type=code";

if(empty($code)) {
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Login with Instagram</a>';
}
```

Upon click of the link above, the user will be redirected to the `$redirect_uri` but with the code value in the URL.

This works fine for me via browser. But, I can't quite seem to load the `$url` and get the `$code` from the URL via command. Is there anyway to generate an access token via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can accept arguments from the command line:

Call the script, like so:

```
php /path/to/script.php code client_id
```

Then, in your PHP script, you can use the following to access the arguments:

```
<?php

$code = $argv[1];
$client_id = $argv[2];

// TO-DO: Validate the user input
// rest of your script...
```

Note that the first argument `$argv[0]` is always the name that was used to run the script.

Comment: Yes, but how does this help me redirect to `http://testsite.com/redirect.php?code=123456789`?

Comment: @Lance: You can obtain the code by loading the URL contents, using `f_g_c()` or cURL. But I don't understand what you mean by redirect. You're running the script from within the command line, so "redirecting" doesn't make much sense. Could you explain?

Comment: Once the `code` parameter in the URL is valid, the rest of my script can get the access token and thus, works fine. But, how can entering `php script.php` in the terminal effectively load `php script.php?code=123456789`?

Comment: @Lance: Why? You cannot populate a `$_GET` array from the command-line. You should pass the arguments as I mentioned above and access them using `$argv` array.